# Queue data deletion ( dequeue )

Tags: c++, queue

I am trying to create a function that will delete an Element of the queue from the front. I have inserted some values in the Main function and know I am performing the dequeue function to delete it from the top but it does not work correctly

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
# define N 5
int queue[N];
int front = -1;
int rear = -1;

void dequeue();

int main()
{

}
void dequeue(){
    if(front == -1 && rear == -1){
        cout<<"Queue Underflow !!\n";
    }
    else if(rear == front){
        front = rear = -1;
    }
    else{
        front++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider turning this into a [mcve] so we can see the issue. No idea how you're adding items to the queue so no idea if the logic to remove one is correct or not.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check

```
else if(rear == front)
```

After doing `front++`. Otherwise, you get in a state where the queue is empty (front == rear) and don't detect it. Next dequeue won't work.